# Lost "Letter of Transfer" and can't complete Mae'Var quest

Tags: baldurs-gate-2

I have lost "Letter of Transfer" and can't complete Mae'Var quest. Is there anything I can do to fix the situation?

I have partial solution:

1. Enable debug console (see here[1](https://www.neoseeker.com/Games/cheats/PC/baldursgate2.html))
2. Create item: `CLUAConsole:CreateItem([ITEM NAME])`

The only problem with my solution is that I can't find proper item code.

So the question is:

- What is item code for "Letter of Transfer"
- Is there any other way to fix the quest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item code for the Letter of Transfer is MISC4T.

CLUAConsole:CreateItem(MISC4T) will create another one for you, allowing you to continue the quest.

Comment: I'll check this as soon as I'll get back from work. Thanks!